# How to utilize buisnessHours class instead of time class

Tags: apex, datetime, time, businesshours

I have a main `if` statement in my class that utilizes `CreatedDate.hour()` to execute certain code between 6pm and 8.59am and the ELSE is 9am to 5.59pm which would be within business hours if I could get this working.

The if statement goes like this:

```
if(objLead.CreatedDate.hour() >= 18 || objLead.CreatedDate.hour() <= 8)
    // outside hours logic
else
    // inside hours logic
```

I would like to change this to use `BuisnessHours`. How would that class be used here?

updated code: 
Class:

```
public with sharing class jungoLeadFollowup{
public void leadAlerts(List<JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c> lstNewLead){
    sendAlertsPrivate(lstNewLead);
}

private void sendAlertsPrivate(List<JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c> lstNewLead)
{
    List<JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c> lstLeadToUpdate = new List<JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c>();
    List<Contact> lstTempContact = new List<Contact>();
    List<Task> lstTaskToInsert = new List<Task>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    User addUser = [SELECT Alias,Email,Id FROM User WHERE Name = 'Jason Frangoulis' LIMIT 1];
    for(JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c objLead: lstNewLead)
    {


        if(!jungoLeadHours.isWithinBusinessHours(objLead))
        {

            //Task: After Hours ALERT


            //Email
            if(objLead.JungoLeadsFrc__EmailAddress__c != null) 
            {
                //Email: Off Hours
            }

            else
            {
               //Email: off Hours: to admin
            }
        }



        else 
        {

            //Task "Call New Lead"


            // Task "NEW LEAD RECIEVED"


            if(objLead.JungoLeadsFrc__EmailAddress__c != null)
            {
                //Email: on hours
            }

            else
            {
                //Email: on hours: to admin
            }
        }
    }

    //send email
    if(!lstMail.isEmpty())
    {
        Messaging.sendEmail(lstMail);
    }

    //Insert Tasks
    if(!lstTaskToInsert.isEmpty())
    {
        insert lstTaskToInsert;
    }

    //update Record
    if(!lstLeadToUpdate.isEmpty())
    {
        update lstLeadToUpdate;
    }

}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger JungoLeadTrigger on JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c(after insert){
    JungoLeadFollowup objHandler = new JungoLeadFollowup();
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            objHandler.leadAlerts(Trigger.New);

        }   

}
```

jungoLeadHours class: (renamed it):

```
public with sharing class jungoLeadHours{
    public static BusinessHours defaultHours{
        get
        {
            if(defaultHours == null)
            {
                defaultHours = [SELECT Id from BusinessHours WHERE isDefault = true];
                return defaultHours;
            }
            else 
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        private set;
    }
    public static Boolean isWithinBusinessHours(JungoLeadsFrc__JungoLeads__c record)
    {
         DateTime toVerify = (record.CreatedDate == null) ? DateTime.now() : record.CreatedDate;
         return BusinessHours.isWithin(defaultHours.Id, toVerify);
    }

}
```

Business Hours ScreenShot:[image: Business Hours]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the `BusinessHours.isWithin` method, which requires a `Datetime`. You could do something as simple as:

```
public with sharing class LeadSevice
{
    static BusinessHours defaultHours
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultHours == null)
                defaultHours = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
            return defaultHours;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public static Boolean isWithinBusinessHours(Lead record)
    {
        Datetime toVerify = (record.CreatedDate == null) ?
            Datetime.now() : record.CreatedDate;
        // above would be necessary if you want this functionality
        // to work in an insert trigger
        return BusinessHours.isWithin(defaultHours.Id, toVerify);
    }
}
```

Once that's set up, your original statement (which looks like a check that you are *outside* hours) would be replaced with:

```
if (!LeadService.isWithinBusinessHours(leadObj))
    // do stuff based on being outside business hours
else
    // do stuff based on being inside business hours
```

Comment: so there needs to be a business hours record already created? what is record.CreatedDate?

Comment: then i would just ask if(BusinessHours.isWithin(defaultHours.Id, toVerify);

Comment: The joys of descriptive naming. It tells you if the specified `Datetime` is within business hours. And `record.CreatedDate` tells you when the record was created. Yes, you would have to set up a `BusinessHours` record, but there should be one already set up, I think.

Comment: so where `Lead` is i should put my custom object?

Comment: @Bryan Right...forgot you are using a custom object. Yes, you would change that to reflect the actual `sObjectType` you are working with.

Comment: ok so if i get a buisnesshours record inserted (_mine is blank_) and i get this class inserted. how would i add it to the current setup for it to be checked against buisness hours? i think that might solve my test class problems as well.

Comment: The class is built in and can always be referenced, whether or not you set up any particular hours. If you go to `Setup` > `Company Information` > `Business Hours` you should see one already there.

Comment: excellent i got the buisness hours setup. but i meant how do i make my orginal statement of 'IF(objLead.CreatedDate.hour() >=18)` to use buisness hours instead of the time class?

Comment: Ah yes, I added that to my question.

Comment: it doesnt fire anything off buisness hours

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to convey there. You should be able to use `Test.setCreatedDate` to pass records with various values to this function and get back some that are outside business hours. You may be running into time zone issues if you are not using `Datetime.newInstanceGmt`.

Comment: you commented on my previous question about setCreatedDate not working and not jumping into the IF statement, but now the operation its self even if its after hours will not jump into after hours. As in the businessHours logic does not work.

Comment: Now that its physically after hours. I get an exception that record is read-only

Comment: You should add your updated code and a screenshot of your `BusinessHours` configuration. Without that I can only guess.

Comment: i added all code in use currently and a screenshot of business hours configuration.